# Complicated Lotto Numbers Generator - Python

Tags: python, random

I'm old and am learning python to keep the old noodle sharp and am enjoying it immensely. I have never coded before.

My project is(are) centered on generating Lotto Numbers for fun.  Picking 5 random numbers that don't repeat was pretty easy.

So next I wanted to random generate numbers until 5 numbers from 1 to 70 were generated 10 times. Once that number was generated 10 times it would be my first lotto number and so on and so forth.

See my brutal caveman solution.  It works, I just pick the first 5 from the printed list. And the first from the mega number list. But I'm looking for hints to "beautify" and or Pythony my solution.

Thx Much
SpookyWatcher

```
#My Lotto Numbers

import random

count = 0

lotteryNumbers = []
megaNumber = []

x1 = 0
x2 = 0
x3 = 0
x4 = 0
x5 = 0
x6 = 0
x7 = 0
x8 = 0
x9 = 0
x10 = 0
x11 = 0
x12 = 0
x13 = 0
x14 = 0
x15 = 0
x16 = 0
x17 = 0
x18 = 0
x19 = 0
x20 = 0
x21 = 0
x22 = 0
x23 = 0
x24 = 0
x25 = 0
x26 = 0
x27 = 0
x28 = 0
x29 = 0
x30 = 0
x31 = 0
x32 = 0
x33 = 0
x34 = 0
x35 = 0
x36 = 0
x37 = 0
x38 = 0
x39 = 0
x40 = 0
x41 = 0
x42 = 0
x43 = 0
x44 = 0
x45 = 0
x46 = 0
x47 = 0
x48 = 0
x49 = 0
x50 = 0
x51 = 0
x52 = 0
x53 = 0
x54 = 0
x55 = 0
x56 = 0
x57 = 0
x58 = 0
x59 = 0
x60 = 0
x61 = 0
x62 = 0
x63 = 0
x64 = 0
x65 = 0
x66 = 0
x67 = 0
x68 = 0
x69 = 0
x70 = 0

y1 = 0
y2 = 0
y3 = 0
y4 = 0
y5 = 0
y6 = 0
y7 = 0
y8 = 0
y9 = 0
y10 = 0
y11 = 0
y12 = 0
y13 = 0
y14 = 0
y15 = 0
y16 = 0
y17 = 0
y18 = 0
y19 = 0
y20 = 0
y21 = 0
y22 = 0
y23 = 0
y24 = 0
y25 = 0

while count < 400:
    count += 1
    number = random.randint(1,70)
    #print (number)
    if number == 1:
        x1 += 1
    elif number == 2:
        x2 += 1
    elif number == 3:
        x3 += 1
    elif number == 4:
        x4 += 1
    elif number == 5:
        x5 += 1
    elif number == 6:
        x6 += 1
    elif number == 7:
        x7 += 1
    elif number == 8:
        x8 += 1
    elif number == 9:
        x9 += 1
    elif number == 10:
        x10 += 1
    elif number == 11:
        x11 += 1
    elif number == 12:
        x12 += 1
    elif number == 13:
        x13 += 1
    elif number == 14:
        x14 += 1
    elif number == 15:
        x15 += 1
    elif number == 16:
        x16 += 1
    elif number == 17:
        x17 += 1
    elif number == 18:
        x18 += 1
    elif number == 19:
        x19 += 1
    elif number == 20:
        x20 += 1
    elif number == 21:
        x21 += 1
    elif number == 22:
        x22 += 1
    elif number == 23:
        x23 += 1
    elif number == 24:
        x24 += 1
    elif number == 25:
        x25 += 1
    elif number == 26:
        x26 += 1
    elif number == 27:
        x27 += 1
    elif number == 28:
        x28 += 1
    elif number == 29:
        x29 += 1
    elif number == 30:
        x30 += 1
    elif number == 31:
        x31 += 1
    elif number == 32:
        x32 += 1
    elif number == 33:
        x33 += 1
    elif number == 34:
        x34 += 1
    elif number == 35:
        x35 += 1
    elif number == 36:
        x36 += 1
    elif number == 37:
        x37 += 1
    elif number == 38:
        x38 += 1
    elif number == 39:
        x39 += 1
    elif number == 40:
        x40 += 1
    elif number == 41:
        x41 += 1
    elif number == 42:
        x42 += 1
    elif number == 43:
        x43 += 1
    elif number == 44:
        x44 += 1
    elif number == 45:
        x45 += 1
    elif number == 46:
        x46 += 1
    elif number == 47:
        x47 += 1
    elif number == 48:
        x48 += 1
    elif number == 49:
        x49 += 1
    elif number == 50:
        x50 += 1
    elif number == 51:
        x51 += 1
    elif number == 52:
        x52 += 1
    elif number == 53:
        x53 += 1
    elif number == 54:
        x54 += 1
    elif number == 55:
        x55 += 1
    elif number == 56:
        x56 += 1
    elif number == 57:
        x57 += 1
    elif number == 58:
        x58 += 1
    elif number == 59:
        x59 += 1
    elif number == 60:
        x60 += 1
    elif number == 61:
        x61 += 1
    elif number == 62:
        x62 += 1
    elif number == 63:
        x63 += 1
    elif number == 64:
        x64 += 1
    elif number == 65:
        x65 += 1
    elif number == 66:
        x66 += 1
    elif number == 67:
        x67 += 1
    elif number == 68:
        x68 += 1
    elif number == 69:
        x69 += 1
    elif number == 70:
        x70 += 1
    if x1 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print
    elif x2 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 2")
    elif x3 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 3")
    elif x4 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 4")
    elif x5 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 5")
    elif x6 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 6")
    elif x7 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 7")
    elif x8 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 8")
    elif x9 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 9")
    elif x10 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 10")
    elif x11 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 11")
    elif x12 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 12")
    elif x13 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 13")
    elif x14 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 14")
    elif x15 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 15")
    elif x16 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 16")
    elif x17 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 17")
    elif x18 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 18")
    elif x19 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 19")
    elif x20 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 20")
    elif x21 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 21")
    elif x22 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 22")
    elif x23 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 23")
    elif x24 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 24")
    elif x25 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 25")
    elif x26 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 26")
    elif x27 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 27")
    elif x28 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 28")
    elif x29 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 29")
    elif x30 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 30")
    elif x31 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 31")
    elif x32 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 32")
    elif x33 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 33")
    elif x34 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 34")
    elif x35 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 35")
    elif x36 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 36")
    elif x37 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 37")
    elif x38 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 38")
    elif x39 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 39")
    elif x40 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 40")
    elif x41 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 41")
    elif x42 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 42")
    elif x43 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 43")
    elif x44 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 44")
    elif x45 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 45")
    elif x46 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 46")
    elif x47 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 47")
    elif x48 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 48")
    elif x49 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 49")
    elif x50 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 50")
    elif x51 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 51")
    elif x52 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 52")
    elif x53 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 53")
    elif x54 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 54")
    elif x55 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 55")
    elif x56 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 56")
    elif x57 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 57")
    elif x58 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)# print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 58")
    elif x59 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 59")
    elif x60 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 60")
    elif x61 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 61")
    elif x62 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 62")
    elif x63 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 63")
    elif x64 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 64")
    elif x65 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 65")
    elif x66 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 66")
    elif x67 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 67")
    elif x68 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 68")
    elif x69 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 69")
    elif x70 == 10:
        lotteryNumbers.append(number)#print ("Your 1st Lucky number = 70")
    meganumber = random.randint(1,70)
    #print(meganumber)
    #print (number)
    if meganumber == 1:
        y1 += 1
    elif meganumber == 2:
        y2 += 1
    elif meganumber == 3:
        y3 += 1
    elif meganumber == 4:
        y4 += 1
    elif meganumber == 5:
        y5 += 1
    elif meganumber == 6:
        y6 += 1
    elif meganumber == 7:
        y7 += 1
    elif meganumber == 8:
        y8 += 1
    elif meganumber == 9:
        y9 += 1
    elif meganumber == 10:
        y10 += 1
    elif meganumber == 11:
        y11 += 1
    elif meganumber == 12:
        y12 += 1
    elif meganumber == 13:
        y13 += 1
    elif meganumber == 14:
        y14 += 1
    elif meganumber == 15:
        y15 += 1
    elif meganumber == 16:
        y16 += 1
    elif meganumber == 17:
        y17 += 1
    elif meganumber == 18:
        y18 += 1
    elif meganumber == 19:
        y19 += 1
    elif meganumber == 20:
        y20 += 1
    elif meganumber == 21:
        y21 += 1
    elif meganumber == 22:
        y22 += 1
    elif meganumber == 23:
        y23 += 1
    elif meganumber == 24:
        y24 += 1
    elif meganumber == 25:
        y25 += 1
    if y1 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y2 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y3 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y4 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y5 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y6 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y7 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y8 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y9 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y10 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y11 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y12 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y13 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y14 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y15 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y16 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y17 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y18 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y19 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y20 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y21 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y22 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y23 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y24 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
    elif y25 == 10:
        megaNumber.append(meganumber)
print("Today's Lottery Numbers Are: ")
print(lotteryNumbers)
print("Today's MegaNumber is: ")
print(megaNumber)
```

Thx All for great help.  Especially those who gave direction without solution.  Here is what I came up with in just 1 hour.

```
#My Lotto Numbers

import random

lottoNumbers = []
lottoMega = []
lottoNumberscondensed = []
numbersX = [0] * 71
numbersY = [0] * 26

for count in range(800):
    number = random.randint(1,70)
    numbersX[number] += 1
    if numbersX[number] == 10:
        lottoNumbers.append(number)
    number2 = random.randint(1,25)
    numbersY[number2] += 1
    if numbersY[number2] == 10:
        lottoMega.append(number2)
for item1 in lottoNumbers[0:5]:
    lottoNumberscondensed.append(item1)
lottoNumberscondensed.sort()
print("Todays Lotto Numers are: ")
print(lottoNumberscondensed)
for item2 in lottoMega[0:1]:
    print("Todays Mega Numer is: ")
    print(item2)
```

Comment: Turning all the y`n` and x`n` variables into lists would be a good start. Then, you could just loop through the lists, making your code way shorter.

Comment: The top thing you can do is condense all those x and y variables into lists, then the numeric part of those variables will just be an index. This will also condense those long if statements down to short loops.

Comment: Apologies for the faux pax I will do.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Zeus and Bill the Lizard. Working it now.

Answer (score 4):

Great to hear you're learning Python, and welcome to StackOverflow! You've probably heard that if you have to type something multiple times, you're probably doing something wrong, and your code is a good example how you can simplify things by using the proper tools.

You want to count random numbers. There already are `Counter` objects (to be found in the `collections` module) which would be ideal here, but you want to build stuff yourself, so let's do this:

Instead of building a heap of hardcoded variables (`x1`, `x2` etc.), we want a list of numbers. Let's call it `numbers` because that's nicer than `x`:

```
numbers = [0] * 71
```

Instead of a `while` loop, I'd use a `for` loop:

```
for count in range(400):
    number = random.randint(1,70)
    numbers[number] += 1
```

That's all you need to do to generate your numbers.

You could check if the current number has reached `10` like so:

```
    if numbers[number] == 10:
        lotterynumbers.append(number)
```

and so on. I hope this helps in getting you started. I don't want to spoil the fun of finding out the rest.

Comment: Outstanding!  Thx Tim Pietzcker.  Working it now.  Knew there a way to better do this.

Comment: great answer! strikes the balance well between explaining and not giving the solution. @SpookyWatcher - Welcome to Python!

Comment: You guys are the BEST!!  Thanks very much for the direction with giving the solution(s).  Here is what I came up with within 1 hour!

Comment: Thx again Tim! Excellent help!  I've posted my revised code and it's great.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome and good effort! Here's a cleaner version of your program that achieves the same result:

```
    import random

    lotteryNumbers = []
    megaNumber = []

    # For convenience, you can use dictionaries to store key value pairs, for example z = {1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 10}
    # In the example, the key number 1 has a value of 5, the key number 2 has a value of 8, and the key number 3 has a value of 10, so it would be your lucky number. 
    # In Python, dictionaries are represented by two curly brackets like so:
    x = {}
    y = {}

    # Populate the two dictionaries with numbers from 1 to 70 included:
    for i in range(1, 71):
        x[i] = 0  # Each key number will initially have the value of 0;
        y[i] = 0

    # Your main loop, simplified:
    while len(lotteryNumbers)<5:
        # The loop will keep running as long as lotteryNumbers contains less than five numbers.
        # When the five numbers have been appended to the list, the loop will stop.

        number = random.randint(1,70)

        x[number] += 1  # x[number] gets you the key number's value, e.g. z[1] was 5 in the example.

        # There's no need to check the value of all key numbers with every loop
        # You can just check the value that's been updated:
        if x[number] == 10:
            lotteryNumbers.append(number)

    # Now do the same for the y dictionary, only this time you loop until the list contains only one number:
    while len(megaNumber)<1:
        meganumber = random.randint(1,70)
        y[meganumber] += 1
        if y[meganumber] == 10:
            megaNumber.append(meganumber)

    print("Today's Lottery Numbers Are: ")
    print(lotteryNumbers)
    print("Today's MegaNumber is: ")
    print(megaNumber)
```

I encourage you to learn more about Python dictionaries and use them to your advantage when programming. Check out the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and/or [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) for more information.

To learn about how to write Python code more "pythonically", you can also look into the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

winningLottoNumbers = []
winningMegaNumbers = []

lottoNumbers = [0] * 70
megaNumbers = [0] * 25

for i in range(400):
     lottoNum = random.randint(0,69)
     lottoNumbers[lottoNum] += 1
     megaNum = random.randint(0,69)
     if(megaNum < 25):
         megaNumbers[megaNum] += 1


for i in range(len(lottoNumbers)):
    if(lottoNumbers[i] >= 10):
        winningLottoNumbers.append(i)

for i in range(len(megaNumbers)):
    if(megaNumbers[i] >= 10):
        winningMegaNumbers.append(i)

print(winningLottoNumbers)
print(winningMegaNumbers)
```